# How to set Toast Capable in Windows 10 App

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-runtime, uwp

I want to know how to set toast capable in a UWP App. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and in Package.appxmanifest editor there isn't any option for that. I tried to mannualy edit the xml, msdn says you can add that mannualy like that.

```
<VisualElements 
...
ToastCapable="true">
</VisualElements>
```

But I found the .appxmenifest to be like that

```
<uap:VisualElements DisplayName="Name" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="Sample" BackgroundColor="transparent">
    <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" ShortName="Name">
    </uap:DefaultTile>
    <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
    <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
      <uap:Rotation Preference="portrait" />
      <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
      <uap:Rotation Preference="portraitFlipped" />
      <uap:Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />
    </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
  </uap:VisualElements>
```

How to achieve toast capability? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 10 you're no longer needed to set the ToastCapable flag:

> Hmm, well you definitely need to have ToastCapable set to true in the
>   manifest since 8.1 required that, otherwise your toasts won’t work in
>   8.1 (in 10, we stopped requiring the ToastCapable flag).

Source: [Comment on the official Quickstart guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/#comment-2975)

You can verify it yourself in the [full source code](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/quickstart-sending-local-toast-win10/blob/master/Quickstart-Sending-Local-Toast/Package.appxmanifest#L17-L30) of the quickstart on GitHub.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't any ToastCapable flag in the sample code and It works. Thanks for the answer, but I wonder, Windows 10 has a list of apps that shows notifications on the device so that you can turn it on and off in the settings app, if there is no such flag than how OS knows which apps are capable of notification? Does when creating an app package some kind of tool analyze the code add that information to the package?

Comment: The Windows 10 store recompiles an app on submission and strips off capabilities which aren't needed. Wouldn't surprise me if it checks for the toast as well, although I'm not 100% sure.